# How do I get the sum of the numbers of repetitions of any number in a column in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

For example:

1
2
3
3
4
5
5
5
6
7
8
9

The result is equal to 3, because 3 repeats once and 5 repeats twice, for a total of three repetitions. I don't want a number to count the first time it is seen.

Comment: I should add that all of these values are in the same column

Comment: Will the numbers always be grouped together? In your example, could another 3 follow 9? If so, would that count as a repetition?

Comment: I thought I saw your original post as the wanted solution being a value of 2? If so I've noted that below in the form of a solution.

Answer (score 2):

The number you want is equivalent to the total count minus the count of unique entries.  Adjust this formula for your actual range:

```
=COUNT(A1:A12)-SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(A1:A12,A1:A12)>0,1))
```

This is an array formula, so it needs to be entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> rather than <kbd>enter</kbd>.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> How many numbers are repeating?

Use the following formula:
`=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(MATCH(G1:G12,G1:G12,0),MATCH(G1:G12,G1:G12,0))>1,1))`

[image]